# Cases are not being created using email-to-case

Tags: email2case, support

Good day, everybody!

The Email-to-Case service is currently experiencing an odd difficulty.
It has worked flawlessly up to this point, but now the email is not open new cases in Salesforce.

-Is there any way to debug this problem?

Your cooperation is greatly appreciated.

P.S. - We attempted to send an email to the Salesforce Email Services Address generated email, but it was unsuccessful.

Comment: Enable debug logs   for Automated case user.  you can check for automated case user under   support settings.    then try to send email to  email service address.   check if you get anyting in debug logs.

Comment: I contacted SF support, who confirmed that my old instance had stopped operating and that the cause to this issue.

Comment: We have a similar problem. Two days ago our email service stopped working. I enabled logging for the user that handles the email service, but nothing happens, nothing shows up. It seems that the emails are not arriving at the email service. I have created a Case with Salesforce Support.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted SF support, who confirmed that my old instance had stopped operating and that the cause of this issue.

Hope it won't happen again.

Comment: We have a similar problem. Two days ago our email service stopped working (which processes emails sent to a special, generated, Salesforce email address). I have also created a Case with Salesforce Support.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the Email-to-Case feature, this is the text of the alert:

The Salesforce Technology team is aware of the Email-to-Case feature degradation impacting customer’s ability to raise Cases across multiple instances. During this degradation, a subset of customers may experience issues while leveraging the Email-to-Case feature to raise Cases. The team is investigating multiple paths to resolve the issue. We will continue to provide an update in 30 minutes or sooner as more information becomes available.